# Invalid IFSC number. The number should be 11 digits in the format ABCD0123456 on stripe

Tags: laravel-5, stripe-payments, payment, cartalyst

I am using **Cartalyst\Stripe\Stripe** I have an issue with creating a bank account token for the Indian bank account

here is my code

`

```
$token = $stripe->tokens()->create([
  'bank_account' => [
    'object'=>'bank_account',
    'country' => 'IN',
    'currency' => 'INR',
    'account_holder_name' => 'Jenny Rosen',
    'account_holder_type' => 'individual',
    'routing_number' => '110000000',
    'account_number' => '000123456789',
    'default_for_currency'=>'false'
    
  ],
]);
```

`

I am getting this error
Invalid IFSC number. The number should be 11 digits in the format ABCD0123456.

Version I am using
"laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
"cartalyst/stripe-laravel": "7.0.*"

Answer (score 1):

The `'routing_number' => '110000000'` and  `'account_number' => '000123456789'` are US test bank account details.

You would want to select `India` in the dropdown to get the list of India test bank account numbers here : https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing#account-numbers